# Как отправить запрос на сайт у которого нет API?

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

Пишу мобильное приложение для сайта у которого нет своего API. Как мне создать мобильное приложение, работающее как клиент-серверное приложение. Как отправлять запросы на сайт и получать данные? Не могу понять, как парсинг может помочь в этом. Если например кнопка, на сайте через которую осуществляется отправка описана как

```
<button  class="ty-btn__primary ty-btn__big cm-form-dialog-closer ty-btn ty-btn" type="submit" name="dispatch[call_requests.request]" >Отправить</button>
```

не содержит в себе ссылок.

Comment: в форме которая она стоит есть адрес? вот туда она и отправляет

Answer (score 1):

Предложу два варианта:

1. Берете сниффер и смотрите, какие запросы и куда идут. Далее эмулируете эти запросы в Вашем приложении и парсите результаты (например, с помощью [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/)).
2. Внимательно смотрите исходник страницы и вычисляете что и куда отправляется, ну а далее так же эмулируете.

Если выберете первый вариант, то в качестве сниффера можно выбрать какой-нибудь [плагин к браузеру](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-sniffer/ndfgffclcpdbgghfgkmooklaendohaef), нежели нечто низкоуровневое, вроде Wireshark.